# Excel VbScript Quotes issue

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am using Vbscript to write some data into excel then i am saving this excel object as txt file. My problem here is after saving as text file some rows contains quotes ". Below is my code can some body help me recording this.

My Output text file is:

```
"Rules*V*ZBEA*892**0010*10*IBM-01**"                    
30,000.00*01/08/2012*21/08/2012****0000013556*01***2600
"Scale value* *********"
```

problem here is 1st and 3rd row starts and ends with quotes (" ").

code is

```
Dim objXL1,name
Set objXL1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXL1.Workbooks.Add
objXL1.Cells(1 ,1) =  "Rules*V*ZBEA*892**0010*10*IBM-01** "
objXL1.Cells(2,1) =  "30,000.00*01/08/2012*21/08/2012****0000013556*01***2600"
objXL1.Cells(3 ,1) =  "Scale value* *********"
name = objXL1.GetSaveAsFilename(,"Text(MS-DOS)(*.txt),*.txt")
objXL1.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs   name ,21 ,,21 
objXL1.ActiveWorkbook.Close 0
objXL1.quit
```

And here once more issue is I am using SaveAs method for getting file name. When execution comes to this line the file save dialog box hiding behind the main IE window is there any way to get this save dialog box in focus?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because of the whitespace. In your code there is a trailing whitespace in the frist line.

```
"Rules*V*ZBEA*892**0010*10*IBM-01** "
-----------------------------------^-
```

If you would export multiple cells you would need to encapsualte those cells to recognize where a cell value begins and ends.